# How to get rid of trailing whitespace printing a list using stdout python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree, stdout, preorder

I'm printing an output using stdout in python, but it keeps the things it keeps printing has whitespace at the end, and `rsplit()` always gives me an error. Code Below.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.data = d
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


# function to convert sorted array to a
# balanced BST
# input : sorted array of integers
# output: root node of balanced BST
def sort_array_to_bst(arr):
    if not arr:
        return None

    # find middle
    mid = (len(arr)) / 2
    mid = int(mid)

    # make the middle element the root
    root = Node(arr[mid])

    # left subtree of root has all
    # values <arr[mid]
    root.left = sort_array_to_bst(arr[:mid])

    # right subtree of root has all
    # values >arr[mid]
    root.right = sort_array_to_bst(arr[mid + 1:])
    return root


# A utility function to print the pre-order
# traversal of the BST
def pre_order(node):
    if not node:
        return
    if root:
        sys.stdout.write(node.data + ' ')
        pre_order(node.left)
        pre_order(node.right)


def no_spaces(s):
    return ' '.join(s.rsplit())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = []
    for line in sys.stdin.readline().strip().split(" "):
        arr.append(line)
    # arr = [7, 898, 157, 397, 57, 178, 26, 679]
    # Output = 178 57 26 157 679 397 898
    narr = arr[1:]
    print(narr)
    narr = sorted(narr, key=int)
    root = sort_array_to_bst(narr)
    pre_order(root)
```

I with the input `7 898 157 397 57 178 26 679` I get the output 
`178 57 26 157 679 397 898.`  The `.` is to illustrate the whitespace, but note in the actual output it is just a blank space. I've tried to
`sys.stdout.write(node.data + ' ').rsplit()` but get the:
`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'rsplit'.
How can I do this, or are there any alternatives?

Comment: `sys.stdout.write(node.data + ' ')` does not return a `str`, it returns an `int`. What do you think it is *supposed* to return?

Comment: even if I do `sys.stdout.write(str(node.data) + '  ')` it still comes out with the same result

Comment: What? I'm explaining why you can't call `.rsplit()` on the result of `sys.stdout.write(...)`.

Comment: The problem is you are always printing a space at the end. You would have to *not* print a space for the very last write. It's probably easier add a space *before*, and special case the root node not do that. Then there won't be a terminating space.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  If you don't want the space, then don't print it.  For getting spaces only *between* elements, you can set a flag, or make a special case of the first or last element, or simply save them all and `join` the list into your whole output string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to print a space only *between* elements:

```
if root:
    if node != root:
       sys.stdout.write(' ')
    sys.stdout.write(str(node.data))
    pre_order(node.left)
    pre_order(node.right)
```